# When a used car is sold "as-is", does that excuse seller from selling the car with smog certificate in California?

Tags: california, driving, consumer-protection

California law states the seller is always responsible for selling the car with a smog certificate. If the seller sells the car saying it is "as-is" does that excuses him/her from previously obtaining this certificate? Which legal risks the seller would be exposed to if he/she does that?

Comment: A possible exception may be if you're buying from a dealership--and I found a [PDF](https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/wcm/connect/17ea86b8-0894-480f-ba75-fc091b9375ee/11olin02.pdf?MOD=AJPERES) that says a dealer must also provide a smog certificate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, selling a car "as-is" is not a valid reason for not having a smog certificate. According to the DMV [here](https://dmv.ca.gov/portal/dmv/?1dmy&urile=wcm:path:/dmv_content_en/dmv/vr/smogfaq), the smog certificate must have been done within 90 days of the sale. The exceptions are:

- The transfer occurs between a spouse, domestic partner, sibling, child, parent, grandparent, or grandchild.
- A biennial smog certification was submitted to DMV within 90 days prior to the vehicle transfer date (a vehicle inspection report may be required for proof of certification).

There are a few other exceptions based on the type/year of the car like gasoline-powered and older than 1975 or electric-powered.